# PHP/JS clock not showing user's timezone and not displaying seconds as they change

Tags: php, javascript

I have a clock that I am tring to use on my site and it works really well as in it shows the time but there are still two things that I need it to do:

1. I need it to display the time in my timezone, the server's timezone.
2. I need the clock to keep real time.  (i.e., display the seconds as they change)

Code:

```
<script> 
function displayTime() { 
  document.getElementById( "servertime" ).innerHTML = '<?=date("h:i:s A");?>'; 
} 

var serverTime = window.setInterval( "displayTime()", 1200 ); 
</script>
```

Comment: It is posting to: '<span id="servertime">Loading ...</span>'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var serverTime = new Date();

function displayTime(){
    serverTime.setSeconds(serverTime.getSeconds()+1);
    document.getElementById("servertime").innerHTML = serverTime.getHours()+":"+serverTime.getMinutes()+":"+serverTime.getSeconds();
}

window.onload=function(){
    setInterval(displayTime, 1000)
}
```

This will use the time of the users machine.  If you want to set a certain timezone, either set in your PHP configuration file or set it at beginning of your script and then put the value in the new Date javascript function.  Something like:

```
var serverTime = new Date('<?=date("m/d/Y H:i:s T", time())?>');
```

Comment: Isn't using strings in setInterval kind of evil like using `eval` ?

`setInterval(displayTime,1000)` should do it

Comment: It worked!!! it is counting and everything!  Any chance you can tell me why it just says Nah:Nah:Nah when I insert my format? "h:i:s A"

Comment: Yeah in this case its better to remove the parentheses.

Comment: I used your formate code and it just sits there loading and never comes around and shows the time?

Comment: NaN (Not A Number) means its not in the proper format.  Sorry, made a mistake with my PHP portion.  Need to have returned time in the new Date.  I have edited that.

Comment: Not sure what you edited but its still not working see: http://jsbin.com/efadoq/5/

Comment: For JS date formatting have a look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Comment: Im not that good at codeing and have ADHD so... I am not seeing the answer on that page...

Comment: The problem with the jsbin is the fact you are trying to run PHP in a js file.  If the js is in a separate file, rename it to .php and update your script accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Set your timezone with [default-timezone-set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php).

To move seconds you have to use JavaScript increment for Hour, minute, seconds.

Answer (score 0):

something like this should do it

```
var startTime = (function () {
  var el = document.getElementById("servertime");
function displayTime() {
  var d = new Date();
      el.innerHTML = d.getHours() + ":" + d.getMinutes() + ":"+ d.getSeconds();
}
  window.setInterval(displayTime,300)
})()
```

Example on [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/efadoq/1/edit)